# Can not resolve http packet encoded parts

Tags: c#, api, http, gzip, decode

I capture http packet (gzip and chunked format message) from network layer but i don't know how can i decode this packet? I need get simple text from body part, but packet shows encoded characters at two parts, header and body.

[image]

Comment: See following : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/085cc852-a87c-48af-a7c4-7f72f6f6a5c9/how-to-handle-httpwebresponsecontentencoding-gzip-using-webrequest?forum=netfxbcl  You are using http 1.1 so make sure you read all chunks until status is 200 OK.

Comment: Sometimes, that is good solution, but i'm unable to resolve captured pcap packets on sniffy application. At sniffy application if node create new web request, that is increase to cost of the balance (data) on network. We need send another new request in this sample.

Comment: HTTP 1.1 requires sending a Next Packet request if you do not get a 200 done.  If you do not send the Next Packet message you get a timeout.  The best solution is to force server into 1.0 mode by adding     request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;  to your request.  I have never gotten chunked mode (1.1) to work in Net Library.

Comment: Are there any disadvantages between 1.1 and 1.0 ??

Comment: Nothing really.   The responses in 1.0 are going to be larger since you get the data is one lump.  It may be in some systems the max size won't allow huge responses.